# When should the hostname be in ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, hostname

I used to leave `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` when going with some hostname other than `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` with no problems, today I encountered this error:
`Invalid HTTP_HOST header` asking me to add the hostname to ALLOWED_HOSTS, even when I commented out the other hostnames from `/etc/hosts`.
I tried the other projects, it worked with the same settings.

Why is it happening now? What's the use of ALLOWED_HOSTS? And why did it work without filling it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, [Django released 1.10.3, 1.9.11 and 1.8.16](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2016/nov/01/security-releases/) to fix security issues.

Following those releases, Django will check `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS` even when `settings.DEBUG=True`. This protects against a DNS rebinding attack.

If `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is empty, then Django will use `['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1']`. However, if you use any other host, you will now need to add it to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, even when `DEBUG` is `True`